# How do I access nested array object values in PHP?

Tags: php, object

I am using [this unofficial PHP SDK](https://github.com/Wisembly/clearbit-php) for the Clearbit service, to enrich identity data. It taps in to Clearbit's API, which natively returns resulting identity records as JSON. It goes like this...

```
 require_once '/home/mysite/public_html/path/to/clearbit/vendor/autoload.php';
 use Clearbit\Clearbit;

  $clearbit = Clearbit::create('my_api_key');
  $combined = $clearbit->getCombined('satya.nadella@microsoft.com');
```

Per the library's [documentation](https://github.com/Wisembly/clearbit-php), it then performs either:

`$combined->getPerson()` (in my case)

or

`$combined->getCompany()`

If I dump the contents like `var_dump($combined->getPerson()`, I see not JSON but what looks to me like an array object...

```
Clearbit\Generated\Model\Person::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '1db9c8f3-366c-46a1-8612-213b17da133d',
   'fuzzy' => false,
   'name' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'fullName' => 'Satya Nadella',
     'givenName' => 'Satya',
     'familyName' => 'Nadella',
  )),
   'gender' => NULL,
   'location' => 'Seattle, WA',
   'timeZone' => NULL,
   'utcOffset' => NULL,
   'geo' => 
  Clearbit\Generated\Model\Geo::__set_state(array(
     'streetNumber' => NULL,
     'streetName' => NULL,
     'subPremise' => NULL,
     'city' => NULL,
     'state' => NULL,
     'stateCode' => NULL,
     'postalCode' => NULL,
     'country' => NULL,
     'countryCode' => NULL,
     'lat' => NULL,
     'lng' => NULL,
  )),
   'bio' => NULL,
   'site' => NULL,
   'avatar' => NULL,
   'employment' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'domain' => 'microsoft.com',
     'name' => 'Microsoft',
     'title' => 'CEO',
     'role' => 'ceo',
     'seniority' => 'executive',
  )),
   'facebook' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => NULL,
  )),
   'github' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => NULL,
     'id' => NULL,
     'avatar' => NULL,
     'company' => NULL,
     'blog' => NULL,
     'followers' => NULL,
     'following' => NULL,
  )),
   'twitter' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => NULL,
     'id' => NULL,
     'bio' => NULL,
     'followers' => NULL,
     'following' => NULL,
     'statuses' => NULL,
     'favorites' => NULL,
     'location' => NULL,
     'site' => NULL,
     'avatar' => NULL,
  )),
   'linkedin' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => 'in/satya-nadella-3145136',
  )),
   'googleplus' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => NULL,
  )),
   'angellist' => NULL,
   'aboutme' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     'handle' => NULL,
     'bio' => NULL,
     'avatar' => NULL,
  )),
))
```

What I need to do, but don't understand how to, is access some of those individual values - like the `city` that is inside `geo`, for example.

I have read around and tried various, like...

```
  $myperson = $combined->getPerson();
  echo $myperson['gender'];
```

and...

```
$mycity = $combined->getPerson()->geo->city;
```

But, truth be told, I don't yet know what I'm doing, and need to learn a bit.

I'm aware that questions with similar titles have probably been asked and answered, but it's possible my question itself is not even correct or that I don't have my terminology correct.

Answer (score 0):

this object is combined with other objects. you should use both objects to retrieve the value like the city.

Something like this:

```
$person = $combined->getPerson();
$geo    = $person->getGeo();
$city   = $geo->getCity();
echo $city;
```

Use functions of **Geo.php** to get values of `Clearbit\Generated\Model\Geo`

Use functions of **Person.php** to get values of `Clearbit\Generated\Model\Person`

Reference:

https://github.com/Wisembly/clearbit-php/blob/master/generated/Model/Person.php
https://github.com/Wisembly/clearbit-php/blob/master/generated/Model/Geo.php

Comment: That yields `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Clearbit\Generated\Model\Combined::getGeo() in /home/mysite/public_html/path/to/mysript.php on line 206`

Comment: `$combined` is the object you have given in answer right?

Comment: check this function it returns the Geo - https://github.com/Wisembly/clearbit-php/blob/3f206bc6eb7f559a39730682a807d692a55c24c8/generated/Model/Person.php#L205

Comment: It's due to nesting. This works... `$person = $combined->getPerson(); $geo = $person->getGeo(); $city = $geo->getCity(); echo $city;`

Thanks for pointing out the custom functions. But it's a bit complex. And, as per the question, I was hoping to use the array value names rather than dedicated functions, ie. by writing a `call_clearbit()` function that would pass parameters corresponding to the array value names, eg. Something like `call_clearbit('geo', 'city')`. That would seem hard to pull off with the dedicated `get*` ones.

Comment: Glad to know that you found the problem. Happy coding.

Comment: If things are static then `call_clearbit('geo', 'city')` will work out, if the result is dynamic no point in developing such function.

Comment: I have updated the answer since I did not know the what $combined contains before And please upvote and accept the answer if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thamaraiselvam, I'm afraid I didn't learn how to access nested array object values in PHP.

Comment: This is how you need to access the value of the nested object because those are tightly coupled with the methods of that class. we cannot simply access like we do for normal arrays.

Comment: They have written that to simplify the complex results. now you do not need to worry on the index of person or geo or city. you simply call those methods they parse and return the exact data we wanted. i hope you understand it